# How to Separate Panels in a JFrame to Separate Classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have this JFrame named `MainFrame` and I'm trying to separate each panel into it's own class. I tried and failed with some errors.

Please see the code that I tried.  What failed and what did I get wrong?

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    private StartScreenPlayerPanel startScreenPlayerPanel;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    System.out.println(screenSize);
                    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {

        startScreenPlayerPanel = new StartScreenPlayerPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, (screenSize.width * 2 / 3), (screenSize.height * 2 / 3));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{1200, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{74, 0, 446, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("The Coin Game",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (int)screenSize.width/30));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTitle = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTitle.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_lblTitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblTitle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc_lblTitle.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblTitle.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblTitle.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblTitle, gbc_lblTitle);

        JPanel StartScreenBtnPanel = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridwidth = 0;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(StartScreenBtnPanel, gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel);
        StartScreenBtnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JButton btnAddPlayer = new JButton("Add Player");
        btnAddPlayer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        StartScreenBtnPanel.add(btnAddPlayer);

        JButton btnStartGame = new JButton("Start Game");
        btnStartGame.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        StartScreenBtnPanel.add(btnStartGame);
```

The code I'm trying to separate to a different Class

```
//      JPanel tblPanel = new JPanel();
//      GridBagConstraints gbc_tblPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
//      gbc_tblPanel.gridwidth = 2;
//      gbc_tblPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
//      gbc_tblPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
//      gbc_tblPanel.gridx = 0;
//      gbc_tblPanel.gridy = 2;
//      contentPane.add(tblPanel, gbc_tblPanel);
//      tblPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

//      table = new JTable();
//      tblPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
//      table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
//      table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
//          new Object[][] {
//          },
//          new String[] {
//              "New Player", "Initial Points"
//          }
//      ) {
//          Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
//              String.class, Integer.class
//          };
//          public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
//              return columnTypes[columnIndex];
//          }
//      });
//      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
//      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(14);
//      tblPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

What I tried

At the end of `MainFrame` Class

```
contentPane.add(startScreenPlayerPanel, startScreenPlayerPanel.getSSPPConstraints());   
    }
    public StartScreenPlayerPanel getStartScreenPlayerPanel() {
        return startScreenPlayerPanel;
    }
```

New Class - `StartScreenPlayerPanel`

```
public class StartScreenPlayerPanel extends JFrame {
    MainFrame mainframe;

    private JTable table;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc_tblPanel = new GridBagConstraints();

    public StartScreenPlayerPanel() {
        JPanel tblPanel = new JPanel();

        gbc_tblPanel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_tblPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_tblPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tblPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_tblPanel.gridy = 2;
        tblPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        table = new JTable();
        tblPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {}, new String[] { "New Player", "Initial Points" }) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { String.class, Integer.class };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(14);
        tblPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public GridBagConstraints getSSPPConstraints(){
        return gbc_tblPanel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to seperate each panel to it's own class

```
public class StartScreenPlayerPanel extends JFrame {
```

Ok, so why are you extending JFrame?

If you want to add a panel to the main frame then you extend `JPanel`:

```
public class StartScreenPlayerPanel extends JPanel {
```

Now because your class "is a" JPanel, you just set the layout manager of the panel and add components to it.

```
public StartScreenPlayerPanel() 
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel( ... );

    add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

There is no need for the `getSSPPConstraints()` method in this class. The "StartScreenPlayerPanel" doesn't know or care how the panel is used. It only worries about the layout of the components in its own class.

The result is a JPanel with a JTable added to the JPanel.

Note: typically when using a JTable you would use:

```
//add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
//add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The scrollpane will automatically add the table header to itself.

Now in your main class you add the panel to the content pane:

```
//contentPane.add(startScreenPlayerPanel, startScreenPlayerPanel.getSSPPConstraints()); 
GridBagConstraints gbc_playerPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_playerPanel.gridwidth = 2;
gbc_playerPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
gbc_playerPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_playerPanel.gridx = 0;
gbc_playerPanel.gridy = 2;
contentPane.add(startScreenPlayeerPanel, gbc_playerPanel).
```

That is the constraints are the property of the class that adds the panel to the content panel.